# Note code in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6.4

I have seen a similar request but did not respond to my problem.
I am building a simple app notes but when I make the login, the data saved on Parse appear for a few seconds on the TableView and then disappear. What am I doing wrong?

thank you all

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

    var noteObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.loginSetup()


    }

    // Parse - Login

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

        if (!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {

            return true

        }    else    {

            return false
        }

    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated( true, completion: nil )
    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError: NSError?)
    {

        println("Faild to log in..")

    }

    // Parse - sign up

    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

        if let password = info["password"] as? String {

            return count(password.utf16) >= 8

        } else {
            return false
        }

    }

    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didFailToSignUpWithError error: NSError?) {
        println("Faild to sign up")
    }

    func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController) {
        println("User dismissed sign up")
    }

    // Parse - logout

    @IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        PFUser.logOut()
        self.loginSetup()
    }

    func loginSetup() {

        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

            var logInViewController = PFLogInViewController()

            logInViewController.delegate = self

            var signUpViewController = PFSignUpViewController()

            signUpViewController.delegate = self

            logInViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController

            self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else {

            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
            self.fetchAllObjects()


        }
    }

    /*


    func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore() {

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")

    //query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork

    query.fromLocalDatastore()

    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if (error == nil) {

    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
    for object in objects {
    println(object.objectId)
    }
    }


    //var temp: PFObject = PFObject()

    //self.noteObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

    //println(self.noteObjects)

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    }else {

    println(error!.userInfo)

    }

    }

    }

    func fetchAllObjects() {

    PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")

    //query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork

    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if (error == nil) {

    PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)

    self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()


    }else {


    println(error!.userInfo)

    }

    }

    }


    */

    func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore() {

        var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")

        query.fromLocalDatastore()

        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                //var temp: NSArray = objects as! [NSArray]
                var temp: NSArray = objects! as NSArray


                self.noteObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }else {

                println(error!.userInfo)

            }

        }

    }

    func fetchAllObjects() {

        PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

        var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")

        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)

                self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()


            }else {


                println(error!.userInfo)

            }

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return noteObjects!.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterTableViewCell

        var object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        cell.masterTitleLabel?.text = object["title"] as? String
        cell.masterTextLabel?.text = object["text"] as? String

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editNote", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var upcoming: AddNoteTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNoteTableViewController

        if (segue.identifier == "editNote") {

            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

            var object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

            upcoming.object = object;

            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        }

    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: thanks for the attention. No, they disappear completely. If I logout and signup reappear for a few seconds and then again disappear completely

Comment: can someone help me?